# PHP process array into var - key

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I've got an array and I'm trying to work out how to loop through it assigning the key as a php variable and the value as the php value.

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cn] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Distributed Site
                )

            [0] => cn
            [description] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Multisite Location
                )

            [1] => description
            [location] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => b0e81b22-4448-48d2-b641-515b6d4f38d7
                )

            [2] => location
            [owner] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => ec19c2db-25ec-4e89-8143-8864417e4f23
                )

            [3] => owner
            [count] => 4
            [dn] => cn=Distributed Site,cn=Local,cn=Sites
        )

)
```

so I would end up with

```
$cn with a value of 'Distrusted Site'
$description with a value of 'Multisite Location'
$location with a value of 'b0e81b22-4448-48d2-b641-515b6d4f38d7'
```

etc..

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you are more asking "what source array should I build to give me the data that I want in a way that I can access/manipulate usefully"? I cannot fathom how you ended up with such a confused array of data like this. Where did you get it from?

Comment: this could help http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Keep the following Quote in mind:If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust your data structure to uniquely use a variable name once and only once:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    ${$key} = $value;
}
```

This is highly discouraged since it ignores PHP fundamentals of using arrays, but this does what you want it to do.